# NSNotification for power Button pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to know which Notification is thrown when user press the power button to lock the device. I check UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification but it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` is fired when user locks device.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

this is what you should be looking at when the power button is pressed.
and also a notification is fired after this named.. `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`